# async signalr hub - returning root task not pushing events

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, signalr

I am using .net 4.0. I have an async signalR Hub which returns a Task. 
The root Task also has a ContinueWith associated to it.

1. When I return the 1st/root task, my Clients.Caller pushes do not appear in the browser.
2. When I return the ContinueWith task my Clients.Caller pushes do appear in the browser.

So this **does** push updates out to the browser....

```
public class MyHub : Hub
  ......

public Task DoSomething()
{

    return myService
      .DoSomeIO()
        .ContinueWith(t => {
           Clients.Caller.helloWorld("hello world");
            //do other stuff
         });
 }
```

this **does not**..

```
public class MyHub : Hub
  ......

public Task DoSomething()
{
   var rootTask = myService.DoSomeIO();
   rootTask.ContinueWith(t => {                                                                          
                               Clients.Caller.helloWorld("hello world"); 
                               //do other stuff
                       });
    return rootTask;
}
```

Why is this?

The reason I am asking is because I can unit test the second scenario, but cannot for the first. Using the second scenario I can start the task, then wait for it to completed and control will jump into the continuewith then I can make my assertions regarding the subsequent service calls.

I cant start the second task as I get a

> Start may not be called on a continuation task

Comment: `Start()` works only in a single special case (when you have a `Task` created using the constructor). In all other cases, `Start()` doesn't make any sense, because the `Task` is either already started or it will start on its own.

Comment: Also, could you explain more about your unit testing issues?

Comment: @svick I use this extension to return me a Task<MyDto> in my test... public static IReturnsResult<TMock> ReturnsAsync<TMock, TResult>(
            this IReturns<TMock, Task<TResult>> setup, TResult value)
            where TMock : class
        {
            return setup.Returns(new Task<TResult>(() => value));
        }.   Then I just call task.Start(); task.Wait();....then make my assertions.  As I mentioned this works well if I return the root task from my hub, but not if I return the continuewith task. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Task`s that can be `Start()`ed should be very rare. Most of the time, you don't need this functionality and as you discovered, it doesn't work with continuations and other kinds of `Task`s (e.g. async `Task`s from C# 5.0).

Because of that I think you should switch to using already started `Task`s everywhere. This means:

1. Changing `DoSomeIO()` so that it returns an already started `Task`.
2. Changing your mock to return a started or even finished `Task`, e.g. by using `TaskCompletionSource`.
3. Removing the call to `Start()` from your unit tests.

When you do all that, you should be able to use the working version in your unit tests without any problems.

Comment: excellent. thanks.  tests now pass and callback to the continuewith, after i added a task.wait() inside my tests.